# Protractor clicks element behind

Tags: angular, iframe, jasmine, protractor, click

I'm using Protractor with the Jasmin framework and testing in chrome.

I have a pagewide iframe below my webapp (for ads). When there is no ad and I click the desired element everything works fine (so the .click() works properly). But when there is an ad, not the desired element is clicked but the iframe behind my app. Somehow Protractor clicks the iframe below my app.

The iframe does not have the tagName of the locator.

My testing code:

```
it('#1 - Player: Play + pause + no download', () => {
    page.getVisiblePlayButton().click();
    browser.sleep(2000);
    page.getVisiblePlayButton().click();
    browser.sleep(2000);
```

}

```
getVisiblePlayButton(){
    let playButtons = element.all(by.tagName('play-button'));
    let playbutton = playButtons.filter(elem => {
      return elem.isDisplayed().then(displayedElement => {
        return displayedElement;
      })
    });
    return playbutton.first();
  }
```

An example of my app: https://soundmarker.com

Comment: Hi @user34491, why don't you check the presence of add and remove before clicking the desired element?

Comment: If there is iframe in your page,  each frame and current page will be treated as an new window. You need to switch to the window where the web element inside firstly, then interact with it, like click, input, get text etc.